# Selenium in Javascript, select element from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get an element from a dropdown list, to select it and go over, but I can't.

I know that the xpath of the element i want to select from the dropdown is:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]
```

while the dropdown window has id `rw_2_input`

the dropdown list lets you to select one of five options: less than 18, 18-40, 40-60, and so on; so I did:

```
// select the dropdown and click on it
const age = await driver.findElement(By.id('rw_2_input'))
await age.click()
```

then

```
// select the dropdown item then click on it

    const ageChoice = driver.wait(until(elementIsVisible((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]"))))
    await ageChoice.click()
```

on top of the file, i used those imports:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, util } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
const expect = require('expect')
const { elementIsVisible } = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/until')
```

My issue is that it says `until is not defined`.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in importing, but I don't know what.
I searched [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index.html) to understand what and how to import, but i had no clue.
If i try to select the element in the dropdown using

```
const ageChoice = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]'))
await ageChoice.click()
```

it says

```
ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
```

Why it should not be interactable?? I don't get it.

*
*
*

***** UPDATE: *****

I managed to work something, but still says "Element not interactable":
what I did is

```
const ageChoice = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Tra 19 e 40')]"))
await ageChoice.click()
```

If I comment out the `.click()` function everything works fine; however I don't have the option selected. How can I select it since it says that it is not interactable?

Comment: Can this help 
util = require('util'),

Comment: sadly not, but i luckily got 
`const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed what is the problem. I'll post here for future reference.

Well, I got that I have **2 dropdown list in my page**, and when I select an option from the first one, **options temporarily "covers" the second dropdown**, Which causes a **"not interactable error"**.

After discovering this (and it took hours, since no one in documentations says nothing about that), I managed how to "wait" for the first dropdown to close.

Basically, you **have to do both** two checks:

a) That the element is visible.

b) That it is enabled.

No checks, no party, so the code becomes:

```
const ageChoice = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Tra 19 e 40')]"))
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(ageChoice), 3000)
await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(ageChoice), 3000)
await ageChoice.click()
```

This way it finally works.

Note that if you use wait-until `elementIsVisible` and `elementIsEnabled` you dont't need to wait-until `elementLocated`: you DO NOT NEED to use this code

```
const ageChoice = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Tra 19 e 40')]"))
```

Instead, this code must be used when you dont do these 2 checks, but the element is at the bottom of a page that contains a lot of dropdowns and it goes in timeout before it is reached. In this case, use

```
const ageChoice = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Tra 19 e 40')]"))
ageChoice.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a quick fix. (Not a solution). You can execute JavaScript on the webpage with this command `driver.executeScript(command)`.

Select the element by ID, or otherwise, that you would like to click and execute JavaScript for example:

`driver.executeScript('document.getElementById('#someID').click()')`