# Select an item from a list with javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using javascrypt with selenium. I need to search and select one of the items in this list, but I am unable to select it. I can find it, but not select the element.
Please help me, thank you very much

```
var input = document.evaluate("//li[contains(., 'ATACAMA')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

var thisregion = input.iterateNext();
thisregion.click();
```

[image]

Comment: Is there are reason you are specifically using Xpath? I'm curious.

Comment: Actually, no, that was the way I was able to find the text I needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium in Javascript, select element from dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480676/selenium-in-javascript-select-element-from-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following below:

```
var input = document.evaluate("//li[text()='ATACAMA']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

var thisregion = input.iterateNext();
thisregion.click();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. For some reason, this list doesn't allow me to click

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have a clue about Xpath, but like you said, there is nothing stopping you from using `querySelector` or in this case `querySelectorAll` instead.

Here I create an array of all the `li` elements and use `.find` to get the element that has the text "Item 3" in it. I then click the element programmatically. All of the `li` elements have `onClick` event inline in the html.

Would this work for you?

```js
let li_item = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'))
              .find(x => x.textContent === 'Item 3');

li_item.click();

function select(element, n) {
  element.style.color = "red";
  console.log(`${n} has been selected!`);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onClick = "select(this, 1)">Item 1</li>
  <li onClick = "select(this, 2)">Item 2</li>
  <li onClick = "select(this, 3)">Item 3</li>
  <li onClick = "select(this, 4)">Item 4</li>
  <li onClick = "select(this, 5)">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work . The list is only texts that are displayed for an input type entry.